# How to migrate EJB 2.1 Project from Websphere 7 to Websphere 8

Tags: migration, websphere, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I have an EJB 2.1 project, works on WebShere 7. I must migrate it to WebSphere 8.
Which one is the better (less effort) approach:

1. First convert the project into an EJB3.1 project then migrate into Websphere. If yes, is it easy to do that by a large project?
2. Adapt the project till it works on Websphere8 (What should be taken into account)

Thanks??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is to do nothing: WebSphere Application Server v8 supports EJB 2.1 just as well as v7.  Why risk changing something that isn't broken?

Comment: There are some new requirements to implement. And The customer wants them to be implemented with EJB 3.1. To achive a uniform, we want to migrate the project into EJB 3.1 (Last Entscheidung)

Comment: Does the EJB 2.1 module use CMPs?  If yes, I would suggest leaving the module alone and creating a new module with the EJB 3.1 features.  Otherwise, I would suggest updating the schema version in ejb-jar.xml to 3.1, and then add new features as required while leaving the old code + XML alone.

Comment: Yes ejb2.1 uses CMP. Can you expand your answer a little bit.

Comment: WebSphere Application Server doesn't support CMP in EJB 3.0+ modules.  You need a 3.0+ module to enable annotation scanning.  Unless necessary, I wouldn't recommend trying to convert the CMPs to JPA, so I would leave the entire module alone and create a new EJB module with your 3.1 features.